# Android Studio: How to Migrate IntelliJ Project to Gradle?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, gradle

I have a project that was originally from IntelliJ.
I followed the instructions below.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-intellij-projects

I'm not sure what to do next. When I load my project in Android Studio it still asks if I want to migrate to gradle. What did I miss?

I am able to use Gradle in the command prompt to build my project, so I assume I just need to tell Android Studio to use Gradle instead of Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I next imported my existing project and it recognized it as a gradle project. I also had to change the gradle version in the gradle.build file to work with the newer version of Android Studio.